# Chrome Dev Editor's Sample Polymer App Displays Blank Window

Tags: polymer, chrome-dev-editor

The polymer app that is generated when "JavaScript Polymer custom element" is selected as the project type in [Chrome Dev Editor](https://www.google.com/events/io/schedule/session/3888155e-32b6-e311-8491-00155d5066d7)'s "New Project" dialog displays a blank screen when run.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

If it is a bug, then how would I get the polymer app to display something?

Answer (score 0):

Judging by your description, it sounds like you are forgetting to refactor for CSP. Right click on your project name, and select `Refactor for CSP`. This will take a while, but when it's done, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the delayed response.

1. Please try the up-to-date Chrome Dev Editor. It's possible that the mentioned template was broken and got fixed since you've submitted the question.
2. Also make sure that you either:

   - have `index.html` or `demo.html` selected when clicking the Run button; or
   - right-click on of them and select `Run...` from the context menu.

What might have happened is that you confused *Polymer element* with a *Polymer app*. The template that've you used generates an element. It also provides an example of the element's usage in form of `demo.html`, and a standard Polymer element description page (based on the `core-component-page` element that reads and displays elements properties from the `metadata.html`) in form of `index.html`. So you have to explicitly run one of those to see something. If you attempt to "run" the element itself (say, click the Run button with `my-element.html` selected), you *will* see a blank screen, just like with any other pure Polymer template, because there is no renderable HTML in there (it's called a *template* for a reason).

If you do indeed want a *Polymer app*, consider using `JavaScript web app (using Polymer paper elements)` or `JavaScript Chrome app (using Polymer paper elements)` project types.

Answer (score 0):

Try at first, to run the bower update from your command line

```
 bower install Polymer/core-elements --save
```

And you might also need to right click on your project directory from the right panel of chrome dev editor and select Refractor for CSP.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly in the example app, the CDE project (bower.json level) was in a subdirectory of the directory that you imported into the editor. Try to import a level deeper instead.